# R: conditionally combine text from adjacent rows while retaining associated information

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

The script needs to:

a) combine text in adjacent rows, the number of adjacent rows may vary, the grouping of rows to be combined is determined by the first row preceded by a  NA and the last row followed by NA,

b) retain row ids for future checking

c) retain a numeric variable associated with one row from each of the adjacent rows to be combined

d) retain the overall order

[image: Before and after tables]

I have achieved this using a for loop and a load of data wrangling with dplyr and stringer.

The for loop is inelegant as I'm struggling with the logic to identify adjacent rows sequentially. This is not important as the grouping variable is just a helper  - but it galls me.

I also wonder if there might be a more efficient way to do this altogether maybe using rowwise and mutate with lead or lag.

Any guidance or pointers would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

tib <- tibble(id = 1:11,
              var = c("a", NA, NA, "b", "c" , NA, "d", NA, NA, NA, "e"),
              txt = c( NA, "the", "cat",  NA,  NA, "sat", NA, "on", "the", "mat", NA),
              nr = c( NA,  NA, 5, NA, NA, 10, 7, NA, NA, 15, 11),
              txt_group = NA_integer_)

# txt_group = helper column for text grouping variable

txt_group_counter <- 1L


for(i in seq_len(nrow(tib))){

  if (!is.na(tib$txt[i]) | !is.na(lag(tib$txt[i]))){

    tib$txt_group[i] <- txt_group_counter
   } 

  if(is.na(tib$txt[i]) | !is.na(lead(tib$txt[i]))){

    txt_group_counter <- txt_group_counter + 1
  }

}


tib1 <- 
  tib %>%
  filter(!is.na(txt_group)) %>% 
  group_by(txt_group) %>% 
  mutate(id_comb = paste(id, collapse = ", "),
         txt = paste(txt, collapse = " "),
         nr = paste(nr, collapse = "")) %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(id = as.numeric(str_extract(id_comb, "^\\d")),
         nr = as.numeric(str_remove_all(nr, "[NA]"))) %>% 
  select(id, id_comb, everything()) %>% 
  bind_rows(tib %>% filter(is.na(txt_group))) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  select(-txt_group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses an auxiliary variable created with a standard `cumsum/diff` trick to define the groups and then `paste` the rows together.

The code does the following:

1. Create a logical variable `eq` that tells whether two consecutive values of `var` are equal. Since the first cannot be equal to the before (before it doesn't exist) I pad with `FALSE`.
2. Some of the values are `NA`, replace them with `FALSE`, all `NA`'s are different from everything else including other `NA`'s.
3. Now a `cumsum` trick, to have the break points, where there are `TRUE` (`var` is different from the next value, see point 1 above), act like a running count. This gives groups by change of `var`.
4. And what is basically the same trick is applied to `is.na(var)`. `cumsum` is very useful to create grouping vectors and deserves a place in a bag of R tricks.
5. The `mutate_at` removes the `NA` values, they would be repeated `NA NA` when the rows would be combined. Like this it's `""` empty strings that are combined.
6. Group by `ok`, `eq` and combine with `paste`. `trimws` is probably not needed but it doesn't hurt, unless the data set is very big and the code is to be optimized for time.
7. Ungroup and remove the temp columns created; replace the spaces in the results by commas.

Here it is:

```
tib %>% 
  mutate(eq = c(FALSE, var[-length(var)] != var[-1]),
         eq = ifelse(is.na(eq), FALSE, eq),
         eq = cumsum(abs(c(diff(eq), 0))),
         ok = cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(is.na(var)))))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var:txt_group), list(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "", x))) %>%
  group_by(ok, eq) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(trimws(paste(., collapse = " ")))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ok, -eq) %>%
  mutate(id = gsub(" ", ",", id),
         var = gsub(" ", ",", var))
## A tibble: 8 x 5
#  id     var   txt          nr    txt_group
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr>    
#1 1      "a"   ""           ""    ""       
#2 2,3    ""    "the cat"    "5"   ""       
#3 4      "b"   ""           ""    ""       
#4 5      "c"   ""           ""    ""       
#5 6      ""    "sat"        "10"  ""       
#6 7      "d"   ""           "7"   ""       
#7 8,9,10 ""    "on the mat" "15"  ""       
#8 11     "e"   ""           "11"  ""
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but your suggested approach combines rows 4 and 5 which is not wanted. Rows 4 and 5 should remain as independent rows.

Comment: @Peter Done, see now.

Comment: This certainly works, which is great! I wonder if you could explain what the code is doing especially the first 4 mutates?